# use Page Curl/Flip animation in React Native for android

Tags: android, react-native, curl

How are you?
I am developing React Native project and I need page flip animation in this project but I can't find proper module.
So I tried to use WebView but It is not working smoothly...
Now, I am trying to make react-native library to use android page curl projects in react-native.
Is it the best solution? or Do you have any idea for that?
Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am sorry but It is not for code...
I want to get an idea to make page curl feature in react native